# Handlebars C# if equals comparison

Tags: c#, .net, handlebarshelper, handlebars.net

I am trying to do if equals comparison on Handlebars .NET. `{{#if xxx}}` is working with boolean values. How can i make `{{#if x = 'foo'}}` comparison in Handlebars .NET ?

Comment: With `#if` you can use the `operators == and != ` only to test for the bool values true or false. `true` means the symbol is defined and `false` means not defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use booleans from your data here, no expressions:

```
{{#if foo}}
    {{helloMessage}}
{{/if}}
```

foo would be a bool:

```
var data = new
{
    helloMessage = "Hello world!",
    foo = true
};
```

.

If you want to handle expression-like behavior, you may also register a block handler like this:

```
Handlebars.RegisterHelper("ifEq", (output, options, context, arguments) =>
{
    if (arguments[0] == arguments[1])
    {
        options.Template(output, context);
    }
    else
    {
        options.Inverse(output, context);
    }
});
```

And use that in your template:

```
{{#ifEq foo ""bar""}}
    {{body}}
{{/ifEq}}
```

But that somehow contradicts my understanding of a template.

Comment: I know that it has to be bool. What i have to do when i need expressions like equals , lower than or greater than ?

Comment: You can't handle this in your template. You need to handle that in your data: 
`var x = "bar"; var data = new {     helloMessage = "Hello world!",    foo = x == "bar" };`

Answer (score 1):

For Handlebars.Net version 2

You may register a helper as follows: (or you may change the name StringEqualityBlockHelper to ifEq)

```
Handlebars.RegisterHelper("StringEqualityBlockHelper", (output, options, context, arguments) => 
{
    if (arguments.Length != 2)
    {
        throw new HandlebarsException("{{#StringEqualityBlockHelper}} helper must have exactly two arguments");
    }

    var left = arguments.At<string>(0);
    var right = arguments[1] as string;

    if (left == right) 
        options.Template(output, context);
    else
        options.Inverse(output, context);
});
```

Usage in hbs template:

```
{{#StringEqualityBlockHelper variable 'string'}}
    // equals 
{{/StringEqualityBlockHelper}}
```

Source: https://github.com/Handlebars-Net/Handlebars.Net#registering-helpers